# Error in opening sharepoint site using SPSite

Tags: document-library, permissions, document, configuration, web-application

I created document using office XML but now i m going to store that document in sharepoint library then it giving me an error like 
["The Web application at {siteUrl} could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application."]

...Note that i have **asp.net web application** running on the same server where sharepoint running. I have added ***Microsoft.Sharepoint*** to my asp.net application but when i going to create the object of SPSite then it giving me this error.

Here is Code...

```
Using memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, True)
                doc.AddMainDocumentPart()
                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document = New Document(New Body(New Paragraph(New Run(New Text("Hello")))))
                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()
            End Using

            Using Site As SPSite = New SPSite("http://sspl:5555/")
                Dim docLib As SPList = Site.RootWeb.Lists("Doc")
                Dim file As SPFile = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add("Test.docx", memStream, True)
                file.Update()
            End Using

        End Using
```

Your reply appreciated. 
Thanx

Comment: Have you verified that you can enter the URL in a browser and reach the site? Do the user your using have permission to access the site?

Comment: @Robban1980 Yes..!! Robban...whenever i going to access it form browser it works fine. And I am logged in with administrator on the server who has full rights on the site.

Comment: I don't know if your using impersonation on your ASP.Net site, if your not the application will run under the ApplicationPool account. That probably don't have access to your SharePoint site. Have you tried running it with elevated privileges i.e. SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // implementation details omitted
}); ? It could also be that you application has a hard time resolving the sspl URL. is the sspl:5555 address in the Alternative Access mapping? Are you using Host headers on the IIS site?

Comment: i face the same problem if you solve this let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if your application run inside sharepoint site then you use object model but if you use your asp.net application not in sharepoint site then you have to use client object model not object model so u get error in SpSite object.

if your application run in sharepoint site then there is a problem of permission

write your code inside

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
// implementation details omitted
});
```

Comment: Hi V_B, @V_B : would you please provide me code of delegate for vb.net..??

Comment: As you suggest i used client object model to upload document. it work perfectly when i run the program in debug mode but when i host it to IIS then it giving me an error (401: Unauthorized).@Ketan03

Comment: Hi @jkundal u have to apply Credentials like so 
ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

Comment: @jkundal when we use client object model we can't use runwithelevated

Comment: So what i need to do to resolve this (401:Unauthorized) error.?? @V_B

Comment: you have to pass credentials like i tell u before
ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

Comment: Hi @V_B i have already pass credentials as you told me but it also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

is this a console application/
If yes...please check the .Net Framekwork and Build-CPU settings

Build should be set to x64 bit CPU and .Net Framwork should be set to 3.5

Thanks,
Ketan

Comment: No Ketan it's not a console application i mentioned that it is my other _**asp.net web application**_ @Ketan03

Answer (score 0):

Is it deployed in IIS or you are using the Visual Studio Internal Websever (running the asp.net app using visual studio ) ??

Firstly, Visual Studio is not 64 bit and Sharepoint binaries are 64 bit, as the **Visual Studio  WebDev WebServer** is 32 bit, it raises this stupid exception :)

If this exception still occurs when u deployed it in IIS, then check the AAM settings for the Application